# How does the activity of Sn chemical potential vary as a function of composition at 900 C?

Tags: structural-formula, phase

This is referring to the Cu-Sn phase diagram in which composition varies along a horizontal line at a certain temperature. I understand that as you move along that line different intermetallic or liquid phases form, but from a activity point of view does the activity go up because of different crystallographic arrangements that are present at different compositions?

Comment: Do you mean $\ce{Sn}$ (as you wrote in the title) or $\ce{Si}$ (as you wrote in the body of the text? Furthermore, it would be helpful if you could include a picture of and/or a link to the phase diagram you are talking about.

Comment: http://www.doitpoms.ac.uk/tlplib/microstructural_exam/cualloys.php

Answer (score 1):

Just above the line, in the two-phase field where $\epsilon$ is in equilibrium with the liquid, the chemical potentials of both Cu and Sn are constant (very likely not equal to each other mind you).  This is a consequence of the tie-line on the Gibbs free energy diagram - check out a book on binary alloy thermodynamics such as Porter and Easterling, Phase Transformations in Metals and Alloys.

At the peritectic point itself, the tie line connects all three phases, $\epsilon$, $\eta$ and the liquid, so the chemical potentials for each element are equal. Dropping the temperature just a smidge leads to two separate two-phase regions, one of $\epsilon$ with $\eta$, and one with $\eta$ and liquid.  The chemical potential of Sn (or Cu) is different in each of those two-phase regions.

Again, Porter and Easterling would be a good reference.